# Can someone help me remove the empty spots in my output list? i tied different methods but nothing seem to be working:(

Tags: python

Can someone help me remove the empty spots in my output list? i tied different methods but nothing seem to be working:(

**Functions:**

```
def clean_list(values):
    values: []
    clean = []
    for i in values:
        if i not in clean:
            clean.append(i)
    print("Cleaned: {}".format(clean))
```

**t01.py:**

```
from functions import clean_list

values = input("values:")

clean_list(values)
```

**The question:**

```
Write and test the following function:

def clean_list(values):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Removes all duplicate values from a list: values contains
    only one copy of each of its integers. The order of values
    must be preserved.
    Use: clean_list(values)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        values - a list of integers (list of int)
    Returns:
        None
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
Add this function to the PyDev module functions.py. Test it from t01.py.

Reminder: this function does not return a list - it updates the list it takes as a parameter.
```

**The sample run**

```
Values: [1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0]
Cleaned: [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 3]
```

**The output I'm getting:**

```
values:1, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0
Cleaned: ['1', ',', ' ', '2', '0', '4', '5', '3']
```

Comment: The `input` function returns `str`.

Comment: What is `values: []` supposed to be?

Comment: @Barmar see this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: @AndréKuljis Shouldn't that be `values: List`? And shouldn't it be in the parameter list?

Comment: `def clean_list(values: List):`

Comment: Your function is supposed to modify the `values` list in place. It prints the cleaned list instead of modifying the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`values` is a string, so you're cleaning the list of characters in the string. Those aren't "empty spots", they're the space and comma characters that you typed in your input.

If you want to treat it as a list of numbers, you have to split it and convert to numbers.

```
values = list(map(int, input("values:").split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Barmar said, you are taking in a string, so two things, your numbers are strings and the datatype is not a list. So in order to make it a list, we can split the string at `,`  use map to turn each element in the list to `int` and list to turn the object into an iterable. Lastly I would like to say, in order to accomplish your goal `set` is your go to.

So below I have provided an example of what you should do instead.

```
def clean_list(values):
    values = list(map(int,values.split(', ')))
    print(f"Cleaned {set(values)}")
```